# MessageBroadcast ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message, broadcast

I'm creating a live chat on Ruby on Rails application and i'm getting trouble to create a spec test. I try to search some examples tests, but I didn't find anything. 
How do I create test to this class?

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    sender = message.person
    recipient = message.conversation.opposed_person(sender)

    broadcast_to_sender(sender, message)
    broadcast_to_recipient(recipient, message)
  end

  private

  def broadcast_to_sender(person, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
    "conversations-#{person.id}",
    message: render_message(message, person),
    conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def broadcast_to_recipient(person, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
    "conversations-#{person.id}",
    window: render_window(message.conversation, person),
    message: render_message(message, person),
    conversation_id: message.conversation_id
    )
  end

  def render_message(message, person)
    ApplicationController.render(
    partial: 'messages/message',
    locals: { message: message, person: person }
    )
  end

  def render_window(conversation, person)
    ApplicationController.render(
    partial: 'conversations/conversation',
    locals: { conversation: conversation, person: person }
   )
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would test this job just like any other [job](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/job-specs/job-spec) with rspec-rails. Perhaps with an [expectation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-7/docs/verifying-doubles/partial-doubles) that `ActionCable.server` receives the proper `broadcast` messages.